# Bayesian concepts : multivariate mixed models

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian

I am working with a multilevel multivariate mixed mode with 4 outcomes. I am having difficulties extracting the variances, coefficients of variations. Could anyone advise?  I am new to bayesian statistics so it has been pretty rough.

Thank you

My example:

bform_1 <- bf(sur_dat ~  age+ (1|countrycode) + (1|regionid), family =lognormal()) +
        bf(number_child ~ parents + (1|countrycode) + (1|regionid),  family = negbinomial()) +
        bf(v ~ country + (1|countrycode) + (1|regionid), family = negbinomial())

fit_2 <- brm(bform_1, data = train, chains = 2, cores = 2)